# Chrome bug workaround: Javascript to steal focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus

When I start Chrome, the new window appears as unfocused & behind the other windows. So I decided to create a workaround; I'll change my homepage url with a file from my disk which one contains javascript to steal focus and then redirect to real homepage.

What is the best method to steal focus, using javascript?

UPDATE: Here is what I attempted...

```
  <html>
     <head></head>
     <body></body>
  </html>

  <script type="text/javascript">

       myWindow=window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", 
          "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes" );
       myWindow.focus();
       self.close();

   </script>
```

However new window looks like popup window, Chrome doesn't display toolbars & adress bar is not editable :(

---

More info about the bug:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/zyLC4Ip96pU

> As far as I'm aware, this has only started on the latest update. If Chrome is already open, when I open a new window of Chrome from a shortcut in the quick launch area of my Windows toolbar, the new window does not take focus, the focus remains on the previous Chrome window. If the focus was not on the previous Chrome window when I launch the shortcut it works fine

Comment: Wouldn't a reinstall of Chrome be a more appropriate solution here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just published a small Chrome Extension which aims at solving this bug! So far it worked great for me (on Window 7 64-bit).
You can find it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-new-window-focus/opmhcfhkhiodgapmnaolhmekmfihmecp

Let me know if you encounter any issues!

Cheers,
Yuvi

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_focus.asp

Comment: Chrome DOES NOT display toolbars :(

Comment: That makes no sense at all... Just reinstall Chrome or the OS (you might have a virus)